# ADB Backup/restore multiple users apps?

Tags: android, adb, backup, restore

I have 2 users defined in my device and i want to backup all applications for all users.

When I try to do this with `adb backup` it works only for first user. Even if i'm logged on another user, backup confirmations shows on first user screen.

Is there any way to backup and then restore other user application data?

PD: I don't have `root` and if i want to get it i need to wipe the device, so won't worth it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some days of research, until this day, is not possible create or restore backups for another user than first one (or principal one) using ADB. It's expected to be added some day in the future but it's not possible right now without `root`.

Comment: Is it possible with root? I haven't found any way to do that even if I have root access.

Comment: It isn't possible, even with root access, until this day yet.